# Enable rbac and aad on existing aks

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-aks, azure-rbac

I have created Azure Kubernetes Cluster, However RBAC and AKS-managed Azure Active Directory are disabled, i want to enable both, but unable to do so

Environment : Azure  AKS Cluster v1.19.11

[image]

I have tried command to enable rbac & aad

```
$  az aks update -g  k8s-azwe-rg-01 -n k8s-azwe-aks-01 --enable-azure-rbac
Cannot specify "--enable-azure-rbac" if managed AAD is not enabled

$ az aks update -g k8s-azwe-rg-01 -n k8s-azwe-aks-01 --enable-aad --aad-admin-group-object-ids 4b-58-0c-7a --aad-tenant-id e-ece23-19d66-9d4
(RBACNotEnabledForAAD) RBAC must be enabled for AAD to be enabled.


$  az aks update -g  k8s-azwe-rg-01 -n k8s-azwe-aks-01 --enable-aad --enable-azure-rbac
(RBACNotEnabledForAAD) RBAC must be enabled for AAD to be enabled.
Code: RBACNotEnabledForAAD
Message: RBAC must be enabled for AAD to be enabled.
```

Comment: mhh thats rlly its stange, i can not reproduce your issue. What version of azure-cli you have installed? You need at least 2.29.0. For me it is 2.33.0 and this worked =  az aks create -g MyResourceGroup -n MyCluster --kubernetes-version 1.19.11 & az aks update -g MyResourceGroup -n MyCluster --enable-azure-rbac --enable-aad

Comment: @PhilipWelz$ az version
{
  "azure-cli": "2.31.0",
  "azure-cli-core": "2.31.0",
  "azure-cli-telemetry": "1.0.6",
  "extensions": {}
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RBAC can only be enabled during cluster creation, you cannot enable it after the aks cluster is formed.

Comment: Yes, it led to recreation of the cluster

Comment: The docs are really confusing here. I'm trying to enable Azure RBAC on an existing cluster (already enabled aad upon creation): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/manage-azure-rbac#integrate-azure-rbac-into-an-existing-cluster
But running `az aks update -n ClusterName -g GroupName --enable-azure-rbac` just shows that this is not possible currently using az-cli (using 2.37). Is the docs then wrong, clearly stating that this is possible?

Comment: Scratch the above.. Needed to update the aks-preview extension to az-cli as well. `az extension update --name aks-preview`

Answer (score -1):

In case anyone is still looking, it is now possible to enable RBAC to an existing cluster.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/manage-azure-rbac#integrate-azure-rbac-into-an-existing-cluster

Comment: Unfortunately that is only partly true. For the situation that @Satyam Pandey is explaining, it is still not possible. 

When you do `--enable-azure-rbac` you are told `Cannot specify "--enable-azure-rbac" if managed AAD is not enable`. 
But when you do `--enable-aad` you are told `RBAC must be enabled for AAD to be enabled.`.

It's Catch 22!